# What is the intent of the 'world' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is [world](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world) intended to be about [global history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_history) aka "world history"? The SE description isn't too clear to me, although it does seem to lean in that direction

> Questions related to the history of the planet Earth and all life and societies and geographical features upon it.

Some questions tagged with it are definitely not of that global-history scope. Reproducing the Wikipedia def:

> World history or Global history (not to be confused with diplomatic, transnational or international history) is a field of historical study that emerged as a distinct academic field in the 1980s. It examines history from a global perspective. It is not to be confused with comparative history, which, like world history, deals with the history of multiple cultures and nations, but does not do so on a global scale. **World history looks for common patterns that emerge across all cultures.** World historians use a thematic approach, with two major focal points: integration (how processes of world history have drawn people of the world together) and difference (how patterns of world history reveal the diversity of the human experiences).

Is the sentence I emphasized a better description? Or is it too narrow?

Comment: Just swagging at it, I'd say that's better, but that that one sentence probably isn't enough all on its own as a description.